# python3: can't install psycopg2

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, pip, psycopg2

Its freshly installed ubuntu 20 and python3.

I am trying to install psycopg2 module as I am trying to play with postgres.

So I started with `sudo apt install postgres`

And now I am trying to get proper python libs but I am running to errors...

`cd /fintoo_python-2/venv/bin/  && ./pip3 install psycopg2`

```
Collecting psycopg2
  Using cached psycopg2-2.9.3.tar.gz (380 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: psycopg2
  Building wheel for psycopg2 (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [37 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
      .
      .
      .
      running build_ext
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.9.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPSYCOPG_DEBUG=1 -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120012 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -DPSYCOPG_DEBUG=1 -I/fintoo_python-2/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/12/server -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/mit-krb5 -c psycopg/adapter_asis.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_asis.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
      In file included from psycopg/adapter_asis.c:28:
      ./psycopg/psycopg.h:36:10: fatal error: libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory
         36 | #include <libpq-fe.h>
            |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      
      It appears you are missing some prerequisite to build the package from source.
      
      You may install a binary package by installing 'psycopg2-binary' from PyPI.
      If you want to install psycopg2 from source, please install the packages
      required for the build and try again.
      
      For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
      <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).
      
      error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for psycopg2
  Running setup.py clean for psycopg2
Failed to build psycopg2
Installing collected packages: psycopg2
  Running setup.py install for psycopg2 ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Running setup.py install for psycopg2 did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [39 lines of output]
      running install
      /fintoo_python-2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
      copying lib/_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
      .
      .
      .
      copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
      running build_ext
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.9.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPSYCOPG_DEBUG=1 -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120012 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -DPSYCOPG_DEBUG=1 -I/fintoo_python-2/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/12/server -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/mit-krb5 -c psycopg/adapter_asis.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_asis.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
      In file included from psycopg/adapter_asis.c:28:
      ./psycopg/psycopg.h:36:10: fatal error: libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory
         36 | #include <libpq-fe.h>
            |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      
      It appears you are missing some prerequisite to build the package from source.
      
      You may install a binary package by installing 'psycopg2-binary' from PyPI.
      If you want to install psycopg2 from source, please install the packages
      required for the build and try again.
      
      For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
      <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).
      
      error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> psycopg2

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

sudo apt-get install python3-dev prints "0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded." so I guess it doesnt do anything..

Unfortunately, "./pip3 install psycopg2-binary" didn't help either..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+%5Bpsycopg2%5D+fatal+error%3A+libpq-fe.h%3A+No+such+file+or+directory

Comment: `sudo apt install libpq-dev`

Comment: **Add answers to following as update to question**. 1) Be more specific about Ubuntu version `20.04` or `20.10`? 2) What was error when you did `pip3 install psycopg2-binary`? 3) Why are you doing `./pip3 ...` instead of `pip3 ...`? 4) Did you activate the `virtualenv` by running the command   `. bin/activate` at `/fintoo_python-2/venv/`?